# Как считать длинную арифметику в NumPy

Tags: python-3.x, cuda, biginteger

Хочу использовать видеокарту для расчетов, но в NumPy нашел только int32/int64 (для CUDA)

Видеокарта 32-разрядная, поэтому эффективно, насколько я понял - это 32 бита

Мне нужно сложение, вычитание, возведение в степень, взятие остатка и умножение целых чисел для максимального числа примерно 2**512. Совершенно не представляю как это сделать, помогите, пожалуйста. Хотя бы где почитать.

Comment: боюсь ваш ждёт [тернистый путь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162140/128-bit-integer-on-cuda)

Answer (score 1):

Numpy, как и библиотека CUDA оперируют строго типизированными данными. Сделано это для скорости.

Как вы уже заметили в вопросе, в Numpy максимальным беззнаковым целым может быть `2**64` или `2**63` для целого со знаком:

```
In [277]: np.iinfo(np.int64)
Out[277]: iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)

In [278]: np.log2(9223372036854775807)
Out[278]: 63.0

In [279]: np.iinfo(np.uint64)
Out[279]: iinfo(min=0, max=18446744073709551615, dtype=uint64)

In [280]: np.log2(18446744073709551615)
Out[280]: 64.0
```

Для того, чтобы оперировать бОльшими числами придется писать [обертку](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6220499/5741205) или же полностью свою библиотеку...